# Dynamically changing the property of spring bean

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

We are having the spring beans and corresponding configuration as follows.

```java
class Parent{
    private String name;
    private Child child;
}

class Child{
   private String name;
   private String age;
}
```

```xml
//bean configuration
<bean name="parent" class="mypackage.Parent" />
```

Now for our utility, user passes me the `Child` object. This object has to be injected into existing `Parent` bean. I tried with `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`, but couldn't get the apt function for this (I wonder if it exists). Is there a way we can achieve this?

Comment: do you have the access to source code of `Parent` class ?

Comment: Since you have are creating an instance of `Parent` using Spring, you can autowire the bean in your class and later call the setter method in `Parent` to set the `Child`.